# Why JSONSchema allows different types constraints simultaneously

Tags: jsonschema

Say I want to restrain JSON object to be an integer > 42 or an array of such integers.

Valid draft-04 schema

```
{
    "minimum" : 42,
    "items" : { "type":"integer", "minimum" : 42 }
}
```

validates `42` and `[52, 62]` but also `"hello"`. So it's wrong way to construct schema.

Besides the correct schema contain redundant "type" field, since "items" implies the array type:

```
{
    "oneOf": [
       { 
          "type": "integer", 
          "minimum" : 42 
       },
       {  
          "type": "array", 
          "items" : { "type":"integer", "minimum" : 42 }
       }
     ]

}
```

### Question

What is the reason for allowing different type constraints at the same time?

Is it a bad design or I just miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/issues/172

The discussion at this link should help you understand why it works the way it does.  The short version is that JSON Schema is designed to be simple, consistent, and flexible.  Those qualities allow greater expressiveness in schemas, but it also allows you to write schemas that you probably shouldn't.  Toward the end of the linked discussion, I give some examples of how that expressiveness is useful and makes JSON Schema less elegant if some of the rough edges are tightened up.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Interesting discussion. So, JSON Schema is broken in a way. I think many problems may be avoided if parameters would imply type. It makes schemas more clear for readers and It even may make schemas even less verbose.

Comment: Well, that's not the conclusion I hoped you would get from that discussion.  I was arguing that requiring (or implying) `type` breaks the JSON Schema architecture and is a bad idea.  But, if you read the whole discussion, you should have enough information to come to your own conclusion.

Comment: There are many good points in discussion but they often contradict to each other. It convinced me that current RFC draft is quite far from ideal. I think there is not much to do about it except writing a better proposal without such pitfalls.